# IIS 6 Error Message

Tags: iis-6

I have Warning message in my IIS 6  Viewer.How to solve this problem?

```
Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Event Category: Web Event 
Event ID:   1309
Date:       11/3/2009
Time:       8:18:20 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   PEB-BL05
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 11/3/2009 8:18:20 AM 
Event time (UTC): 11/3/2009 1:18:20 AM 
Event ID: 6d12e7ec9a314fd59153efb83329b5c3 
Event sequence: 236 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1950175433/Root/myApp
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /attga 
    Application Path: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myApp\ 
    Machine name: MyComMachine

Process information: 
    Process ID: 4528 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: RowNotInTableException 
    Exception message: This row has been removed from a table and does not have any data.  BeginEdit() will allow creation of new data in this row.
```

Comment: Please put a little more effort into your question. Are you developing an application or did you just notice this error in there while poking around?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, more info is really needed.  On the surface it looks like you have a page that is manipulating a table and it encountered an error that was not handled, so IIS reset the worker process (handled your exception for you). Hwo do you troubleshoot? There are a number of ways, but the one I am most familiar with and use most frequently is to attach the debugger (cdb or windbg), set a BP on the exception that is occuring and then wait.  You can then use the debugger to determine the page that is failing and anything more you want.  To learn more about this process I'd recommend a book by John Robbins:

[http://www.amazon.com/Debugging-Applications-Microsoft%C2%AE-Microsoft-Pro-Developer/dp/0735615365](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735615365)

Answer (score 0):

This is an application error caused by what ever is running in the "myApp" folder.

Take a look at whats in there and then come back.